# merging tables - inserting every nth

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the instance where I need to merge 2 tables to one where the result of the second is inserted every nth into the merged table.

to illustrate i have a products table and i need to insert an advert in every nth (say 4th) result of the final output. i have made the assumption the best way to handle these is to keep the two data source tables and merge the desired result into a new table (if theres a better way to use just one table and insert into that I'm interested)

**the main data source: products**

```
var productDataTable = [
  {id: '1', content_type: 'product', name:'t-shirt'},
  {id: '2', content_type: 'product', name:'t-shirt2'},
  {id: '3', content_type: 'product', name:'t-shirt3'},
  // .....
];
```

**secondary datasource** : adverts

```
var advertsTable = [
  {id: 'advert1', content_type: 'advert', name: null},
  {id: 'advert2', content_type: 'advert', name: null},
  {id: 'advert3', content_type: 'advert', name: null},
  // ....
];
```

**desired output of final table required** - an advert has been inserted every nth

```
var feedOutput = [
  {id: '1', content_type: 'product', name:'t-shirt'},
  {id: '2', content_type: 'product', name:'t-shirt2'},
  {id: '3', content_type: 'product', name:'t-shirt3'},
  {id: 'advert1', content_type: 'advert', name: null},
  {id: '4', content_type: 'product', name:'t-shirt4'},
  {id: '5', content_type: 'product', name:'t-shirt5'},
  {id: '6', content_type: 'product', name:'t-shirt6'},
  {id: 'advert2', content_type: 'advert', name: null},
];
```

query example

```
var params = {
  TableName: 'feedOutput',
};

docClient.scan(params, function(err, data){
  console.log(data)
});
```

**Question:** 
what would be the most appropriate way to joint these two tables in this nth manner ? i am using node.js with the aws sdk.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What determines the order of the desired table? What are the partition key and sort key supposed to be?

Comment: partition key is the id

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. But you can keep both kinds of information in one table. And depending on your sorting requirements, you should choose the appropriate ids.